# Запятая между частями ССП при наличии придаточного

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, сложное-предложение, ссп

*Если слово (словосочетание) уже зафиксировано в словарях, следовательно, значение не является непривычным[,] и кавычки не нужны.*

По идее, запятая ставится, потому что отсутствие кавычек скорее обусловлено отсутствием непривычности (согласно правилу), нежели тем фактом, что слово зафиксировано в словарях, — ни придаточное, ни вводное слово "следовательно" не являются общим элементом. Однако в источнике почему-то запятой нет. Видимо, авторы решили просто перечислить два следствия из факта наличия слова в словарях, не делая акцент на истинном порядке обусловленности. Верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1) *Если слово (словосочетание) уже зафиксировано в словарях, (2) следовательно, значение не является непривычным  и (3) кавычки не нужны.***

То, что здесь фактически **два следствия объединены в одно,** видно по структуре и интонации (**два нераспространенных предложения (2) и (3) произносятся в одну фразу, паузы нет**).

**Сравнить**: *Если слово (словосочетание) уже зафиксировано в словарях, следовательно, значение не является непривычным, и **поэтому** кавычки не нужны.*

В этом случае мы рассматриваем два следствия (при наличии наречия ***поэтому***).

О грамматике предложения

Это сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной связью. Подчинительный союз двуместный: ***если.... следовательно.***

Answer (score 1):

А вводное нам не мешает, пусть относится, к чему хочет. Можно его и убрать. Мысленно.

Главное - это общее придаточное, общий элемент, как ни крути. Оно "обобщает" условие: привычность слова (словосочетания) и ненужность кавычек.

Если оное зафиксировано в словарях!

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Если слово (словосочетание) уже зафиксировано в словарях, (2) следовательно, значение не является непривычным и (3) кавычки не нужны.**

Я понимаю Ваш довод, но в пользу отсутствия запятой есть два довода: структура предложения и связь между (1) и (3), которую все-таки можно проследить, минуя (2), то есть *если слово уже зафиксировано в словарях, то кавычки не нужны*. Таком образом, счет 2:1  пользу отсутствия запятой.

Примечание. Слово *следовательно* в данном предложении употреблено неудачно, если не сказать просторечно. Предпочтительней одно из двух:

**Если слово (словосочетание) уже зафиксировано в словарях, то значение не является непривычным и кавычки не нужны.**

**Данное слово (словосочетание) уже зафиксировано в словарях, следовательно значение не является непривычным и кавычки не нужны.**

Comment: Что именно вы имеете в виду, когда говорите, что структура предложения — первый довод в пользу отсутствия запятой?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что идет придаточное, а за ним два главных, связанных союзом *и*. Такая структура располагает считать придаточное общим.